# How to do Youtrack Agile Board time estimation to have a good burndown chart?

Tags: scrum, youtrack, burndowncharts

We have a project which is deploying thorough Scrum. In Scrum you will update your estimates during the sprint and set them with the remaining time. We use youtrack for tracking the project and particularly its Agile Board. We used to update estimation -as I told- during the sprint with remaining time.

But I found that decreasing the estimations (when work goes on and estimate of remaining time should be decreased) wouldn't be reflected in burndown chart. It just draw that chart by sum of Whole sprint tasks estimation and sum of fixed sprint task estimations. A change in estimation will just scale whole chart, not be reflected as works goes on.

How should we change our estimates to watch it on burndown chart?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on Software Engineering SE or Project Management SE instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 5.0.* version youtrack's burndown chart doesn't relies on 'old' estimation values. Ideal burndown and issue estimations values are taken from current values. In 5.1 it will have such ability (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-22390)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you need two fields. Original Estimate and Remaining Work. This will allow you to keep track of the % complete of the original size.

Comment: It seems that there is no "remaining work" in YouTrack... Am I wrong?